# Creating ASP.NET website with membership database in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, authentication, asp.net-membership

I am trying to find out how I can add the membership database to my Mircroft SQL Server and then be able to reference it from a ASP.NET application. Basically, I created a new website app project, how do I create the asp_net membership database and then tell my website to comunicate to it?, I found this

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx
```

But that is not what i want, it creates a database file in the App_Code folder, I want it to access my Microsoft SQL Server and then there have such database. I am new to this setting up login merbership stuff and some pointers would be of great help. I thought maybe there was like a wizard where you could specify the server etc..?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really nice Walkthrough of that [here](http://www.shiningstar.net/ASPNet_Articles/SqlMembershipProvider.aspx). You just need to use aspnet_regsql.exe to create the necessary objects in SQL Server and use Membership provider settings to use this new connection string, it is explained [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-vb) under the Step 4: Specifying the Provider and Customizing Its Settings.

Hope that helps.

Cheers